# scikit-learn TfidfVectorizer ignoring certain words

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I'm trying TfidfVectorizer on a sentence taken from wikipedia page about the History of Portugal. However i noticed that the `TfidfVec.fit_transform` method is ignoring certain words. Here's the sentence i tried with:

```
sentence = "The oldest human fossil is the skull discovered in the Cave of Aroeira in Almonda."

TfidfVec = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf = TfidfVec.fit_transform([sentence])

cols = [words[idx] for idx in tfidf.indices]
matrix = tfidf.todense()
pd.DataFrame(matrix,columns = cols,index=["Tf-Idf"])
```

output of the dataframe:

[image]

Essentially, it is ignoring the words "Aroeira" and "Almonda".

But i don't want it to ignore those words so what should i do? I can't find anywhere on the documentation where they talk about this.

Another question is why is the word "the" repeated? should the algorithm consider just one "the" and compute its tf-idf?

Comment: whats 'words' in your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tfidf.indices` are just indexes for feature names in TfidfVectorizer.
Getting words by this indexes from the sentence is a mistake.

You should get columns names for your df as `TfidfVec.get_feature_names()`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The output is the giving two the because you have two in the sentence. The entire sentence is encoded and your getting values for each of the indices. The reason why the other two words are not appearing is because they are rare words. You can make them appear by reducing the threshold.

Refer to min_df and max_features:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html